# Error logging php - error_reporting(0) not having desired effect

Tags: php, error-handling

I've got a pretty simple page which fetches a url and parse some data.

I have built into my page some error handling in the event that the response is a 404 error.

However, I can't seem to stop php from spitting out the following errors

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(http://url-to-retrieve.com/123.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /var/www/html/maickl/procs/get.php on line 84

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/maickl/procs/get.php on line 91
```

I start the page with

```
error_reporting(0)
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening, why these errors are not being suppressed (it seems to be only  on this page), and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `error_reporting(0);` shoud disable error reporting, which means you should not get that error -- are you sure it's not re-enabled somewhere ?

But what you are probably looking for, actually, is not to change [`error_reporting`][1], but to disable [`display_errors`][2], which can be done using some code like this one :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```

With this :

- errors / warnings will not be displayed on your website, which is nice for end-users *(technical errors should never be displayed)*
- but `error_reporting` is not disabled, which means errors can/will still be logged -- see [`log_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) and [`error_log`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log).

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I thought that should hide all errors, but it isn't and I'm not even sure how I would 're-enable' error_reporting. I tried using the display_errors as you provided, but I'm still getting the same responses. Very strange....

Comment: Sorry about that, I got it. I was including a file which for some reason had a different error setting. thanks

Comment: OK :-) Thanks for your comment *(I have to admit the first was let me wondering... Nice you posted the second one too ^^ )*. Have fun !

Answer (score 6):

Also remember that if you have set a user defined error handler function, then `error_reporting()` settings are completely ignored.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Turning off error reporting is one way of doing it, but I would suggest simply fixing the error or adding appropriate error handling.

```
try {
     //try to do the following
     $content = file_get_contents('file/to/try.txt');
} catch (Exception $e) {
     //do this in case of an error
     die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you're not forgetting output by `debug_print_backtrace()`. You can still capture it and prevent it from being output to the client using the following:

```
ob_start(); 
$error = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $error.print_r(debug_print_backtrace(),1));
ob_end_clean();
```